# MVC6 - ViewDataDictionary always require LoginViewModel

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

So i recently merged an older project from MVC6 vNext Visual Studio 2015 CTP 2 into CTP 3 due to my migrations not worked in the older one.

My code runs fine in the new project however all pages besides my index page give me the same error:

```
The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Models.HeaderViewModel',
but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Models.LoginViewModel'.
```

Im really at a loss as when i break my code i can see the models beeing passed are correct etc, yet somehow the ViewDataDictionary wants a loginViewModel.

**Example:**

View code:

```
@model Models.HeaderViewModel
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "report";
  ViewBag.Header = "reports";
}
// HTML CODE
```

Controller code:

```
 public IActionResult Index() {
      HeaderViewModel model = new HeaderViewModel();
      // DO STUFF
      return View("Incident", model);
 }
```

Link on _Layout.cshtml that redirects:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Incidents panel", "Index", "Incident", null)
```

currently my MapRoute is just the basic one from the example preview:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
        routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "default",
                   template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Im really at a loss as why this is happening as it worked fine in the previous version. I hope someone with a better knowlagde can see what im doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance,

*Sorry for any grammar errors, english is not my primary language.*

Comment: if this is the exact code your application has then this error should not come

Comment: This is the exact code, sadly.

Comment: Weird...could you share how your view structure is? (the folder structure of views)

Comment: Hi Kiran, im sorry about the late response - i was pulled for another project.

My structure is very basic, i had to edit some names etc due to company policy.

here is the structure:
http://i.imgur.com/rZM7yZd.png